# Android Google SignIn result is null

Tags: android, google-authentication

I am integrating Google sign-in for Android and I want the id_token back so I can authenticate with my server. I followed all the steps as in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

If I request just `requestEmail()` then I am getting back the profile information but if I add `.requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))` then `result.isSuccess()` is false and I am not getting any account information back. Any ideas?

```
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .build();
```

onActivityResult:

```
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                    String idToken = acct.getIdToken();
                    mIdTokenTextView.setText("ID Token: " + idToken);
                    // TODO(user): send token to server and validate server-side
            } else {
                    mIdTokenTextView.setText("ID Token: null");
            }
```

If I try to call any method on "result" then I get a Null pointer error...

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=9001, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.test.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Have you already done stuffs in google developer console?

Comment: see into "result.getStatus().getStatusMessage()" here you should find error message

Comment: @an_droid_dev I am getting Null pointer error..         
          java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=9001, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.test.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SOLVED!

So after 6 hrs of breaking my head, found the issue. Apparently when you create config.json using your SSH1 google automatically creates a Web OAuth2 key associated with this project. What I noticed was Google created 3 projects with the same name (one for firebase, one for Web and another not sure)

So grab the Web client ID that is linked with the same Android project. Oh Google!

Comment: Oh my gosh you solved this for me. I spent several hours jacking with this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, for me the third client_id inside the oauth_client inside the google-services.json file worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found after researching about this issue and found that result is throwing null pointer Exception due to
`android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in activity manifest.

So make sure you Change launchmode to **'singleTop' or just dont give** any launchmode for the your activity for e.g: signinActivity;

Comment: This answer makes no sense because he never published his `manifest`

Comment: This answer really does the job. On JellyBean the login failes in singleInstance mode, but succeedes in singleTop, while on Oreo it works in both modes.