# Google Sign in but result code is 0

Tags: android, webview, google-play-services, google-signin

I want to create a Google sign for my app but my result code from `onActivityResult()` is 0

In my `onCreate()` Method I start the function `startSignInIntent()` like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //some other stuff
        view.loadUrl(myURL);
        startSignInIntent();
}
```

This is the `startSignInIntent()`

```
private void startSignInIntent() {
        GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
                GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN);
        Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
```

This is the `onActivityResult()`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "data : " + resultCode + " | " + data  + " || " + RC_SIGN_IN + " ||| " + requestCode);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // The signed in account is stored in the result.
                GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
            } else {
                String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
                if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                        .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
            }
        }
```

This the result of the log in the function `onActivityResult()`

> 0 | Intent { (has extras) } || 2 ||| 2

After I select an account of the the pop-up where I can choose my account. I get this screen with ok but when I have that the login already failed. See photo:
[image]

Comment: Try checking if you have the correct OAuth key properly configured for your app. According to this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45211254/5995040), the OP noticed that the Auth key is also associated with other project that create the issue. Also you can check the following implementation of [Try Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start), for code implementation. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot thanks it worked!

Comment: Nice, I post this as an answer

Comment: For me, all I had to do was add the debug key to my Firebase project and reboot my device: keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore. Note the keystore password is "android". Add at the bottom of your project: Project overview->Project settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try checking if you have the correct OAuth key properly configured for your app. According to this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45211254/5995040), the OP noticed that the Auth key is also associated with other project that create the issue.

Also you can check the following implementation of [Try Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start), for code implementation:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}
```

Also, some additional information provided by OP, you need to make sure you have signed the APK when you are testing it. See the documentation about [Sign Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) for detailed information about it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Add this also to your solution that you need to sign the apk when you test. Otherwise it will not work

Comment: Thanks for changing it. You really helped me out!

Answer (score 19):

I've had the same bug, requestCode was always 0 (RESULT_CANCELED).

Decision was to enable google sign in in firebase console.

Firebase console -> Your project -> Authentication -> Providers -> Google -> and switch it on.

In my case link was like this

> https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/{PROJECT NAME}/authentication/providers

Comment: This is probably true if you are using the firebase analytics? I was getting the error so I followed the steps and along the way had to make a couple of changes to the project. I think the change that mattered was changing `applicationId` to match with the one which I had registered with Google developer console. The `package` in AndroidManifest.xml and `applicationId` are now the same in my app and without the firebase changes, I get -1 as the return value for the signIn!

Comment: This was 2 years ago, so maybe something has been changed.

Comment: @EugeneP. nothing has changed. Enabling Google signin made it works. -.-

Comment: This answer solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to set the publishing status of your OAuth consent screen to **In Production status** instead of **Testing status**.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem with Android Emulator. It turns out that the emulator was disconnected from the Internet that why firebase it was throwing above mentioned error.

Comment: or on a real device if it's not online ... 

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to share my experience even though it is not applicable to the original case.  My search landed here because I had the same problem - startActivityForResult returns instantly with resultCode = 0.

My cause was the wrong package name.   I have an app with a few variants each of which has a different package name.  Google Sign-In requires that the Android app's package name matches one of the Google API console's Android projects' package name.  I set up a project for one variant, but did not for others.  Once I created a project for the Google API Console, the sign-in started to work flawlessly.

Comment: I forgot that I recently added multiple build types and flavors, each with their own applicationIdSuffix. After creating OAuth-Client-IDs for all of them it works fine again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had forgotten to add the project ID to AndroidManifest.xml.
Thus:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
           android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

and in the folder res/values create a file ids.xml and set the ID of the project

```
<string name="app_id" translatable="false">numberOfProject</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this going on specifically on android jellybean and it turned out to be that if the signin activity launch mode I was using was not standard or singletop in the manifest the onActivityResult() would return immediately without actually waiting for the result.

```
 <activity
       android:name=".SignInActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:permission="com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.permission.LAUNCH_FEDERATED_SIGN_IN"
        tools:replace="android:launchMode"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got it fixed... I was trying to clean up some OAuth IDs in the Credentials but removed a wrong one.

- visit [Start Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)
- click `Configure a project`
- select your project / create one
- choose `Android` then fill in your `package name` & `SHA-1`
- copy and use the (Web application) `client ID`

I found that this setup will create 2 OAuth 2.0 Client IDs:

- OAuth client (Type: Android)
- Web client (Auto-created for Google Sign-in) (Type: Web Application) <- the one I missed

Answer (score 0):

The Play Store has a Sha-1 key; you need to add that key to your Firebase project. And in Firebase, you need to accept Google authentication.