# Google signin with firebase on Android not working

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

My app has been publish for a while and Google Sign in was working fine untill now. It just suddenly stopped working. I've checked everything includeing SHA-1 fingerprint, client_id etc.

Upon testing i've found out that the result activity doens't return RESULT_OK.

```
private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient

private var googleSigninLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){

    if(it.resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(it.data)
        try {
            val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            account.idToken?.let {token->
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(token)
            }

        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            Log.d("LOGIN_DEBUG", e.message.toString())
        }
    }else{
        //This is where the code reaches and I am getting RESULT_CODE 0 in the logs
        toast(this@MainActivity, getString(R.string.there_was_an_error))
        Log.d("LOGIN_DEBUG", it.resultCode.toString())
    }
}


val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

    googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)


google_signin.setOnClickListener {
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent

        googleSigninLauncher.launch(signInIntent)
        toast(this@MainActivity, resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))
    }
```

I've looked at a lot of questions but none of the solutions are working for me.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "It just suddenly stopped working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. Does your app crash? If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo ..its doesn't crash.. nothing happens. when I tap on sign in..I get the account selector, after selecting the account nothing happens. I do not get any errors in the log. Also, if you check above, I mentioned what's happening. the onResult RESULT_CODE doesn not return OK. it turns a RESULT_CODE of 0.

Comment: [Here](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-android-app-using-multiple-firebase-products-in-kotlin-16aade81ffec) you can find a working solution.

Comment: thanks @AlexMamo , unfortunately that doesn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please check your google-services.json file ?

check if your publishing SHA-1 is existed.

If play console generates the signing key so the SHA-1 of this key have to be added in firebase then download google service file again

you can find it in you app page in play console (Release -> Setup -> App Integrity)

And if you publishing with your signing key generate the [signing report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67490537/android-studio-4-2-doesnt-show-signing-report-in-the-gradle-bar) from android studio (also you can find the SHA-1 in play console) and make sure this SHA-1 added to firestore then download the file again

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47377458/6799230).

> Try checking if you have the correct OAuth key properly configured for your app. According to this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45211254/5995040), the OP noticed that the Auth key is also associated with other project that create the issue.

Additionally, make sure you have signed the APK while you're testing. Read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) for signing your app.